# How to inject dynamic div in list view and fire action on dynamic div in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have used ng-repeat to generate the list. In each list item there is one button. By click on button, action() function fire and return value. Once the action() function return value I wanted to do below 
1) Insert div () and show message inside div along with action2 button (ng-click="action2({{return value from action() function}})" and pass value return by action() function).

Below is code snippet

```
<ul class="list-group" ng-repeat="item in items">
    <li class="list-group-item">{{item.title}} 
        <div ng-click="action(item.id)">action</div>
        <INJECT NEW DIV>
    </li>
</ul>
```

1) Above will generate list view

2) When I click on action div, should process the action and inject generated div (`<INJECT NEW DIV>`)

3) `<INJECT NEW DIV> = <div ng-click="action2({{return value from action function}})">Action 2</div>`

4) `action(item.id)` is normal jquery/javascript function

Answer (score 0):

Along with the item.id pass $event to grab the clicked element and then use jquery insertAfter() to insert the new element after the current clicked element with desired attributes

Comment: Yes upto inject new div (<INJECT NEW DIV> is ok but when we inject using jquery then angularjs event not fire on new injected div (ng-click="action2({{return value from action() function}})"). Also I need to pass   action() function return value to injected div and only for that list item. So similar action fire for other list item so need to pass value to specific list item.

Comment: did you try $scope.$apply(). can you show the code for the function?

Comment: Sorry for late response. Basically action function is just to append the div         var msg = '<div ng-click="action2()" class="col-xs-12 alert alert-success">action done</div>'; $(element).after(msg); after I used this action2() is not fire event. Also can you please tell me where $scope.apply() need to add. Thanks!

Comment: you need to add $scope.$apply() after the element has been appended in the function